# Selecting columns from resultset into array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get a number of columns from a PDO resultset into seperate arrays, so resulting as such:

```
<?php
  $query = 'SELECT col1,col2 FROM tbl_imaginary';
  ...
  $col1 = array(col1_row1, col1_row2,...);
  $col2 = array(col2_row1, col2_row2,...);
?>
```

I know I could loop through the resultset with fetch, but it seems more efficient to use fetchAll(PDO:FETCH_COLUMN). However, once you do this, you can't perform it again unless you perform execute() on the statement handle again. I get why, you can't empty the cookie jar and then do the same again unless you fill it up again - kind of thing. So I thought I would copy the statement handle object and fetch columns of it as such:

```
<?php
  $sh->execute();
  for ($i=0; $i<$sh->columnCount(); $i++)
  {
     $tmp_sh = $sh;
     $output[$i] = $tmp_sh->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
  }
?>
```

However, this, just like doing fetchAll() on the original statement handle itself, outputs only the first column and not the second.

If anyone would be so kind to explain this behaviour to me and / or suggest a solution I would be most grateful.

Thank you very much in advance for your time.

*Edit: So basically I want to get 2 (or more) columns from one resultset as seperate arrays, just like you would if you would perform 2 (or more) individual queries on 1 single column. The above is mostly an explanation of how I've tried to do this so far.*

Comment: Why do you want the columns in two separate arrays?

Comment: what's the point in selecting separate columns?

Comment: I have quite a few uses for this, one of them being for example using in_array($col1) to check if a value passed by a form checkbox is a valid value (the checkbox values are off course loaded from the same column). Now, I could use 2 queries to do this, but if I need these two columns (from the same table) for this purpose, it seems overhead to do 2 queries, if it could be done with 1.

Comment: Are the entries of `col1` guaranteed to be unique then? Does the order of the rows matter? Or is it just the `col1`->`col2` association which matters?

Comment: I simply need two arrays of these columns, just like you would have when you would make two queries selecting one single column, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it with one query. What I've put forward in my question is merely the way I've been trying to do so, sorry if it's confusing. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @NwN: What I'm trying to say is it makes no sense to store the two columns in two separate arrays. It makes much more sense to store them in pairs in a single array, since each `col1` corresponds to a `col2`. Can we see the code where you use col1 and col2?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need two separate arrays?

```
$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl_imaginary');
$statement->execute();

foreach($sth->fetchAll() as $row) {
    echo $row['col1'], $row['col2'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please see my comment above.